# is there an alternative to .toggle() for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently as per Jquery [site](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/) .toggle() has been depreciated after 1.8 version. So is there any alternative to .toggle() as i need the function for menu app in which I need to hide and show contents of a div based on button click

I have already accomplished the task according to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darshkotecha/6g3cko1h/1/) but I am already loading 1.12.4 version of jquery on my site for other usage

my Js function code

```
function hideToggle(button, elem) {

  $(button).toggle(
    function() {
      $(elem).hide();
    },
    function() {
      $(elem).show();
    }  );
}

hideToggle(".button1", ".iframe1");
```

So is there a way to prevent loading two versions of jquery

Comment: From the page you link to:  *"The .toggle() method is provided for convenience. It **is relatively straightforward to implement the same behaviour** by hand"*

Answer (score 5):

This is basically what `hide` and `show` are doing.

CSS

```
.hidden {
 display:none;
 /* you could also use !important here */
}
```

JQuery

```
  $('#someElement').toggleClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 2):

They do not seem to have replaced it with an equivalent method.  However, you can do this:

```
$(button).on('click', function() {
    if ($(elem).is(':visible') { // if $(elem) is visible
        $(elem).hide(); / hide it
    } else { // if not
        $(elem).show(); // show it
    }
```

Comment: How would you show it, if it is not in the DOM ?

Answer (score 2):

Bizarrely, the simple solution to this is a [*different* `toggle` function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). This function toggles the display of the element.

Your function could be simplified to

```
function hideToggle(button, elem) {
  $(button).click(
    function() {
      $(elem).toggle();
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.toggle()` on click to achieve exactly the same thing:

```
$(".button1").click(function() { $(".iframe1").toggle();});
$(".button2").click(function() { $(".iframe2").toggle();});
```

Updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/6g3cko1h/3/ including an updated version of your utility-style setup method:

```
function hideToggle(button, elem)
{
    $(button).click(function() { $(elem).toggle(); })
}
```

Comment: At least one of thousands solutions works! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are not understanding right what was deprecated. The toggle function is valid.
Which is "Display or hide the matched elements".

The current documentation for toggle is - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

so

```
$('button').toggle()
```

Would hide the element if it was visible, or show it - if it was visible

Comment: Sorry, but OP is clearing using `$(button).toggle(function...)` which *is* the deprecated  toggle function and is looking for an alternative.  The *other* toggle function is not deprecated as you assert here.

Comment: I agree. I think @lonesomeday 's answer is the best